# Overriding subscript / operator[] for an array of types

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

I'm 99% sure the answer to this is 'no dice', but I'll try anyway...

I'm trying to override `operator[]`.

I know how to override it for invocations on a given type:

```
struct Huh {
    int x;
    int operator[](float idx) { return -1; }
};

Huh h;
cout << h[123.4f] << end;  // works, spits out -1
```

But what if I want to change the way I subscript an array of these types:

```
Huh h[10];
Huh h2 = h[123.4f];  // invalid!!
```

It appears this is a non-changeable C++ behavior.  That is, the `operator[]` for type "Huh[10]" (or any array type) is off-limits.

Or, is there some way to define `operator[]` for an arrayed type?

I tried making `operator[]` a free function only to discover that's disallowed in C++.  Any other ideas?

Comment: What for? Why not just replace the “arrayed type” by your custom type? What kind of logic are you trying to get?

Comment: You can't do it, and I'm glad.

Comment: In the real code, my 'Huh' type itself is a vector - it has N elements side of it.  I index into that type using an index with N values too.  In the end I want it to do a gather.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No dice. You can't overload a "pointer to an object"s methods, as a pointer is not an object with operators to be overloaded.

Comment: Arrays generally act like pointers when accessing them (there are a few corner cases where it doesn't, but this generally holds).

Comment: That doesn't mean that there are any pointers in this question. If you want to go into detail and introduce the identity `a[b] === *(a+b)` then that's fine, but you'd have to do so explicitly and talk about not being able to overload `+` for native pointer types. Further, there are _definitely_ no "pointer to an object's [member functions]" here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The pointer is the `a` in the expression `a[i]`.  Because `operator[]` is defined to work on pointers, not on arrays.  It only appears to work on arrays because of the implicit pointer conversion.  So there weren't any explicit pointers, but there was one generated by the expression.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Did I not just say that?